# REACT useLocalStorage custom hook is difficult to understand

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

It is difficult for me to understand this custom React hook. The code works, but I understand only some parts. It is a useLocalStorage hook. I will be grateful for any feedback.

This is my App.js file.

```
import "./App.css";

import useLocalStorage from "./useLocalStorage";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage("NAME", "");

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div>My name is {name}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is my useLocalStorage.js file.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function getSavedValue(key, initialValue) {
  const savedValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

  if (savedValue) return savedValue;

  return initialValue;
}

function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {

console.log(key);
console.log(initialValue);

  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    return getSavedValue(key, initialValue);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  });

  return [value, setValue];
}

export default useLocalStorage;
```

I understand how the **savedValue** (in useLocalStorage.js) is passed to the App.js file. I just retrieve it with the **getSavedValue** function, like this.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    return getSavedValue(key, initialValue);
  });
```

And later, I pass it to the App.js with these two lines.

Firstly, I return the **value** in the useLocalStorage.js

```
return [value, setValue];
```

Secondly, I pass the **value** variable into the **name** variable in the App.js file.

```
const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage("NAME", "");
```

This is how the passing of the **savedValue** from useLocalStorage.js to App.js works. I think.

But how does it work the other way around? How is the updated **name** variable passed from App.js to useLocalStorage? It seems to me that only **“NAME”** and **initialValue** are passed from App.js to useLocalStorage.js. Like this.

```
const [name, setName] = useLocalStorage("NAME", "");
```

As a result, in the useLocalStorage.js, I am able to access the **“NAME”** and **intitialValue(“”)** with the console.log statement.

```
console.log(key);
console.log(initialValue);
```

And it works. But I do not have this option for the updated **name** variable. Or do I? How do I access the updated **name** variable (available in the App.js) in the useLocalStorage.js???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your first question ("How does the updated name variable get passed from App.js to useLocalStorage"):
The value returned by `useLocalStorage` is the same as the `useState` it uses internally. In other words,
your current setup is maintaining state in two places: in the `useState` (internal to `useLocalStorage`) and
in local storage itself.

To your second question ("Do I have access to the updated name variable"):
Yes. Your `name` variable is `value`.

While your code may have the intended effect, I don't think it works the way you think it does. Here's
what will happen on the first render (assuming the key hasn't been set in localStorage yet):

1. Your `App` component will call `useLocalStorage` with "NAME" and "" as parameters.
2. Your hook will call `useState`. It is passing a function that is only executed once (on first render). After that, this function is never called again. In this function, you call `getSavedValue`. This will try to get the key from local storage and return it if it exists. If not, it will return the initial value.
3. Finally, you return the `value` (which now is an empty string, the `initialValue`) and a setter.
4. Your App.js uses the `value` and `setValue` (which it calls `name` and `setName`) to populate your form.
5. At some point in the future, your `useEffect` hook runs and saves the previously-returned initial value to local storage. Now, the key should be set

Now, you start typing in the input. Here's what will happen:

1. The `setName` (which recall is actually `setValue`) is called. This simply updates the internal state of the localStorage.
2. That update will cause a re-render of the `App` component.
3. Your `useLocalStorage` hook will get called again. This time, it won't call the `getSavedValue` function. It will return whatever was set when you called `setName`/`setValue` in step 1.
4. At some point in the future, your `useEffect` hook fires again in `useLocalStorage`, which will save the value to local storage.

In a nutshell, you are using localStorage as an out-of-band storage mechanism that is updated independently of the actual component state. If you refresh the page, it will initialize from the local storage (instead of using the `initialValue` you pass in).

Comment: **This part of your explanation was critical.**

Now, you start typing in the input. Here's what will happen:

The setName (which recall is actually setValue) is called. This simply updates the internal state of the localStorage.

**I did not know this was possible. Everything makes sense now. Thank you.**